# Display times in 5 minute intervals in database

Tags: mysql, sql, time, intervals

We've got a big database which registers positions of tracked vehicles. So, every second, we have thousands of positions coming.
The aim is to filter the SQL request, because we have too many datas. If I do a simple "select time from positions", i'll get a lot of position times. But i'm not interested in all of them.
So my idea was to create an interval. I want the database to give me the position time every 5 minutes.

The database uses STR_TO_DATE function to get position time.

My data is like this :

```
2019-06-05 00:00:00
2019-06-05 00:01:00
2019-06-05 00:01:00
2019-06-05 00:02:00
```

And i want this :

```
2019-06-05 00:00:00
2019-06-05 00:05:00
2019-06-05 00:10:00
2019-06-05 00:15:00
```

As you see here, the position times "01" "02" .. have disappeared. Because i don't want them. I want the position time in 00:05:00  , then in 00:10:00  , BUT I don't want the position time between these intervalls.

```
select 
    distinct time 
from 
    positions 
where 
    time>STR_TO_DATE('05/06/2019 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
    and time<STR_TO_DATE('06/06/2019 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
limit 1000;
```

How can I do this in my case please? How can I change my code ?

I'm using Mysql workbench version 6.3.

Comment: So what is your original data?And what is your version of mysql?

Comment: I don't see the criterion for `00:01:05` to become `00:10:07`

Comment: No, you didn't understand what I want. It was just an exemple, I just want to display these positions time but not all of them, only display by intervals of 5 minutes.
So all the hours between 00:00:00 and 00:05:00 disppear, then 00:05:00 to 00:10:00 disappear  (keep only the data of the 5th minute)

Comment: I saw the other related topics, but it's not my case. My case is when you have as I showed an STR_TO_DATE.
How can I do in my case? I'm new in SQL, so i don't easily understand

Comment: I agree, I didn't understand what you want. And I still don't.

Comment: I've edited my message, I hope you'll understand this time.

Comment: I suppose your 'time' column is of type DATETIME or TIMESTAMP and the values may report seconds as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the `time` is of type DATETIME or TIMESTAMP and that you want only the records where the seconds within the time equal 0 and the minutes within that time are a multiple of 5, you may try the following:

```
WHERE MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time), 300) = 0
```

I'm not sure whether this is correct since I don't know how this function behaves with respect to leap seconds. I cannot test this in my environment.

In order to resolve this, you may try this:

```
WHERE MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time), 5) = 0
  AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time) = 0         -- if relevant
  AND EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM time) = 0
```

Comment: It takes a lot of time when having big database, but I think it's the only way

Comment: Try adding an index on the `time` column or partition the table.